# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que al guarda un string en la variable F , efectue la multiplicación o la suma?

Tags: array, c, string, dev-c++

1.2 Programa que permite elegir a un usuario entre multiplicar y sumar 2 números

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    float A, B, C;
    char D[11] = "multiplicar";
    char E[5] = "sumar";
    char F;

    printf("Dame un numero A");
    scanf("%f", &A);
    printf("Dame un numero B");
    scanf("%f", &B);
    printf("¿Que desea hacer con los numeros insertados?");
    scanf("%s", &F);

    if(F == D)
    {
        C = A * B;
        printf("El resultado de la multiplicacion es %f", C);
    }
    if(F == E)
    {
        C = A + B;
        printf("El resultado de la suma es %f", C);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Ni sumo ni multiplico los numeros");
    }
    getche();
    return 0;
}
```

Este es el problema que intento resolver y aqui esta mi solución mi problema es que no se como guardar el string de "multiplicar" y el de "sumar" y que al guardarlo en la variable F efectue las operaciones

Comment: Tu código como texto por favor, no hay necesidad de usar imágenes

Comment: Tengo 40 años, vista cansada y miopía. Soy incapaz de leer tu captura de pantalla. Por favor pon el código, no una imagen.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no existe un compilador de C++ que de soporte a compilar imágenes.

Comment: Gadi Wisar si la respuesta de @MrDave1999 solucionó tu problema, por favor marcala como correcta.

Answer (score 1):

El programa tiene varias fallas:

**1.** Esta línea de código:

```c
scanf("%s", &F);
```

La variable `F` es de tipo `char` y usas en el `scanf` como especificador de formato un `%s`, cuando en realidad debería ser : `%c` y esto se debe, porque lo que necesitas pedir es un caracter, no una cadena.

Por lo tanto, el código corregido quedaría así:

```c
//Limpiamos el búfer del teclado antes de pedir el caracter.
while(getchar() != '\n');
printf("¿Que desea hacer con los numeros insertados?");
 scanf("%c", &F);
```

**2.** Esta expresión:

```c
F == D
```

Esta mal, debido a que, la variable `F` es de tipo `char` (guarda el código ASCII de un caracter) y `D` es un puntero implícito que apunta hacia al primer elemento del arreglo. Es decir, es evidente que la condición **NUNCA** dará `true`, porque un código ASCII  no será igual a una dirección de memoria. Por lo tanto, el programa siempre mandará este mensaje por consola: `Ni sumo ni multiplico los numeros`.

**Posible solución:**

La condición debería ser así:

```c
//La comparación es válida, porque comparamos código ASCII de caracteres.
if(F == 'm')
{
    //code
}
if(F == 's')
{
   //code
}
else
{
    printf("Ni sumo ni multiplico los numeros");
}
```

Obviamente deberíamos eliminar la declaración de las variable `D` y `E`, ya que no se necesitan.

**3.** En la segunda condición faltó anteponer la palabra clave `else`.

Es decir, debería ser así:

```c
if(F == 'm')
{
    //code
}
else if(F == 's')
{
   //code
}
else
{
    printf("Ni sumo ni multiplico los numeros");
}
```

Si no lo agregas, tendrás un error lógico, debido a que, si la primera condición se cumple, la segunda no se cumplirá, pero si el caso contrario y por ende, imprimirá por pantalla el mensaje de: `Ni sumo ni multiplico los numeros`.

**Otra solución** es dejando las declaraciones `D` y `E` como cadenas, pero necesitarás usar la función [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) para comparar con la cadena que ingrese el usuario. Adicionalmente, deberás cambiar la declaración de `F`, ya que no puede ser una variable de tipo `char`, debido a que, solo almacenaría un caracter. Así que para poder guardar múltiples caracteres, necesitamos declararlo como un arreglo de caracteres.

**Propuesta:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    float A, B, C;
     //Le sumo +1 porque faltaba el espacio para el caracter nulo
    char D[11+1] = "multiplicar";
    char E[5+1] = "sumar";
    char F[12];

    printf("Dame un numero A");
    scanf("%f", &A);
    printf("Dame un numero B");
    scanf("%f", &B);
    printf("¿Que desea hacer con los numeros insertados?");
    scanf("%12s", &F);

    if(strcmp(F, D) == 0)
    {
        C = A * B;
        printf("El resultado de la multiplicacion es %f", C);
    }
    else if(strcmp(F, E) == 0)
    {
        C = A + B;
        printf("El resultado de la suma es %f", C);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Ni sumo ni multiplico los numeros");
    }
    getche();
    return 0;
}
```

**Recomendaciones:**

**1.** Si optamos por la segunda solución, no sería necesario declarar los arreglos `D` y `E`, debido a que, se puede pasar la cadena literal directamente al segundo parámetro de la función `strcmp`.

**2do Propuesta**:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    float A, B, C;
    char F[12];

    printf("Dame un numero A");
    scanf("%f", &A);
    printf("Dame un numero B");
    scanf("%f", &B);
    printf("¿Que desea hacer con los numeros insertados?");
    scanf("%12s", &F);

    if(strcmp(F, "multiplicar") == 0)
    {
        C = A * B;
        printf("El resultado de la multiplicacion es %f", C);
    }
    else if(strcmp(F, "sumar") == 0)
    {
        C = A + B;
        printf("El resultado de la suma es %f", C);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Ni sumo ni multiplico los numeros");
    }
    getche();
    return 0;
}
```

**2.** No es recomendable usar la cabecera [conio.h](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h), debido a que, no pertenece a la biblioteca estándar de C, por lo tanto, si te interesa la portabilidad (puede que el compilador no lo reconozca y haya errores de compilación), no lo deberías usar.

En vez de usar `getche()`, podrías hacer uso de la función [getchar()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) para pausar el programa, debido a que, esta rutina si pertenece a la biblioteca estándar de C, por lo tanto, en cualquier compilador de C debería estar disponible.

Ejemplo:

```c
int x;
printf("Ingrese un numero:");
scanf("%d", &x);
//Limpiamos el búfer del teclado
while(getchar() != '\n');
//Pausamos el programa 
getchar();
```